# Can a blazor parameter be an object with only the getter's for properties exposed?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am implementing something similar to [Pass tokens to a Blazor Server app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#pass-tokens-to-a-blazor-server-app)

I have an object that I pass from _host to app.razor.

Due to pre-render, the OnInit logic is called twice.

The first time, the values in the object are as expected.  The second render, the values in the object are the default values.

After a bit of trial-and-error, I discovered that the problem is that I had protected the object properties (ex: public string AValue { get; }) and and populated the props through the constructor.

Even if I change the props to be {get; private set;}, the behavior is the same.

The only way that I can get this to work right is to make the props full public get/set.

I really didn't want to do expose the set methods on these prop's as I like to make these objects immutable (as much as you can within c#)

questions:

1. Any doc's that describe this or other limitations when passing parameters into razor component?
2. Is this just a problem with the _host/app.razor parameter passing, or is it something that would affect any component parameter passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first render occurs on the server, so the same object instance you created is available during the render process.

The HTML goes to the client to display to the user, and then the browser performs the same render again. Obviously the same instance cannot exist on the client and server so Blazor has to send it as JSON.

The serialiser it uses is the new `System.Text.Json` one, which will not set property values unless the property setter is public, that is why you are getting default values.

As far as I know, there is no way to switch out the default JSON library to Newtonsoft.

You could pass a JSON string as the parameter and have your component deserialise it into the target object using Newtonsoft.